# Evaluate $\int_\gamma z \ \Im(z^2) \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

> I am trying to find $$\int_\gamma z\ \Im(z^2) \ dz,$$
>   where $\gamma$ is the unit circle traversed once, anticlockwise.

My attempt:

let $\gamma(t)=e^{it}\implies \gamma'(t)=ie^{it} \ \ \ \ t\in[0,2\pi]$.
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma z\ \Im(z^2) \ dx&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{it}\sin(2t) \ ie^{it} \ dt\\
&=i\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\sin(2t) \ dt\
\end{align}
Now, I let 
\begin{align}
I&=i\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\sin(2t) \ dt\ \\
&=i\left(\left[\frac{e^{2it}}{2i}\sin(2t)\right]_{0}^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{i}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\cos(2t) \ dt\right) \\
&=-\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\cos(2t) \ dt \\
&=-\left(\left[\frac{e^{2it}}{2i}\cos(2t)\right]_{0}^{2\pi}+\frac{1}{i}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\sin(2t) \ dt\right) \\
&=i\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\sin(2t) \ dt\
\end{align}

Where am I going wrong? Wolfram says the answer is $-\pi$.

**edit**

I can see an alternative approach. We could express the integrand as, $$(\cos(2t)+i\sin(2t))\sin(2t)=\cos(2t)\sin(2t)+i\sin^2(2t).$$ But I prefer using integration by parts and would like to see the solution achieved via this approach.

Comment: Sorry, this was a mistype. Thanks for spotting this

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?" You are not, only, you "proved" that $$i\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\sin(2t) \ dt=i\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\sin(2t) \ dt$$

Comment: The result given by integration by parts was not what I expected haha I expected a multiple of $I$ would appear on the RHS, which I could bring to the LHS and solved like this. I remember seeing a similar method in real calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=i\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\sin(2t) \ dt=i\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2it}\dfrac{e^{2it}-e^{-2it}}{2i} \ dt=\dfrac12\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{4it}-1\ dt=-\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

You have that

\begin{align}
2I
&=
\int_0^{2\pi}\, -e^{2it}\Big(\cos(2t) -i\sin(2t)\Big) \,dt
\\&=
\int_0^{2\pi}\, -e^{2it}\Big(\cos(-2t) +i\sin(-2t)\Big) \,dt
\\&=
\int_0^{2\pi}\, -e^{2it}\,e^{-2it} \,dt
\\&=
\int_0^{2\pi}\, -1 \,dt = -2\pi
\end{align}